# How to connect an external hard drive to Lubuntu virtual machine in VirtualBox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive

I'm trying to get some files off of my virtual machine by connecting my Seagate BackupPlus external hard drive to it. I've gone into the settings of my virtual machine, enabled the USB Controller and the USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller, and added a filter for my hard drive. When I boot up my virtual machine and select my hard drive from the Devices menu, I get this error:

"Failed to atttach the USB device Unknown device 0BC2:A013 [0100] to the virtual machine lubuntu1.

USB device '' with UUID {ca0c17b1-a471-4dbe-90e7-621662873d1f} is busy with a previous request. Please try again later."

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a similar post on the VirtualBox forums [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=45349).

Try ejecting the external drive from your host before attempting to connect in the VM.

Comment: I got it to recognize the drive. Thanks for the help!